# How can we achieve utf8 encoding?

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, ascii, encode

How can we achive utf-8 encoding using ***utf8bytes=unescape(encodeURIComponent(unicodecharacters))***

As all I know is that `encodeURIComponent` converts strings to UTF-8 character encoding if that is the case then why we use unescape with it to get UTF-8 encoding. Unescape will return `ASCII` string from `hexadecimal encoding`, hence it will decode string. I have referred this http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In JavaScript, a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2) is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. When you want a different character encoding, you use a different data type, such as Buffer or UInt8Array. And, so, no Unescape does not return an ASCII string; though it might return a string with only [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoints.

(But, yes, the very common convention to put non-ASCII in a URL (after the protocol, domain name, and any port, password and username) is %-encoding some bytes, and the very common convention for which bytes to put in a URL is to UTF-8 encode text. Ultimately, it is up the server to interpret.)